# Get SoftLayer load balancer location

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getAdcLoadBalancers.json` to retrieve all the account Load Balancers.

I looked at the data types returned and it isn't obvious how to get the location of the load balancer.  Can you help?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the retrieved data ? it may be more clear

Answer (score 0):

You could use an objectMask to retrieve additional relational data.
For example, the next mask retrieves the load balancer hardware and the data center where it’s located.

> objectMask=mask[loadBalancerHardware[datacenter]]

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getAdcLoadBalancers.json?objectMask=mask[loadBalancerHardware[datacenter]]
```

The next links provide further information:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters